# Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices

Tags: jss

Can somebody help me on this

> Error Rendering
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer:
>   Cannot read property 'context' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'context' of undefined at
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxa16.local\dist\my-first-jss-app\server.bundle.js:1:56408
>   at at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
>   at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.d__71.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.d__131.MoveNext()
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.d__101.MoveNext()
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.d__101.MoveNext()
>   --End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.Helpers.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[TResult](Func`1
>   func)    at
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Comment: If you run the app in disconnected or connected mode do you see the same error? The error is being thrown inside your `server.bundle.js`, line 56408. Can you find that line in `server.bundle.js` (and maybe the surrounding lines also) and paste it here?

Comment: Yes the app is working fine in both disconnected and connected mode. Here is the content from the line 56408 managed to get :) key: "componentWillUnmount", value: function () {
                                              }  key: "render", value: function () {
                                    var t = this.props.component, e = Object.assign({}, this.props);
                                    return delete e.component, e.sitecoreContext = this.context.contextFactory.getSitecoreContext(), a.default.createElement(t, e)
                                }

Comment: Thanks. Can you zip up your JSS project (including the `node_modules`) folder and share it with us - jss@sitecore.net - via drive, dropbox, etc...

Comment: @AdamWeber Hi Adam I have shared the files it will be from jagatheeshmenon@gmail.com

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please confirm if it is fixed. Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'ROUTE_CHANGE_COMPLETED' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROUTE_CHANGE_COMPLETED' of undefined at t.a (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc91.sc\dist\jssadvancedappreactweb\server.bundle.js:1:849429) Layout Service response is fine: {"context":{"pageEditing":false,"site":{"name":"website"},"language":"en"},"name":"Home","displayName":"Home","fields":{"Text":{"value":"<p style=\"line-height: 22px;\">1- From a single connected platfo

Comment: We had the same error with Sitecore JSS with vueJs, we updated the Packaged to the latest :
Server Package (Tech Preview 9.0.1 rev. **180412**)
and
Infrastructure Package (Tech Preview 9.0.1 rev. **180412**)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to repro the issue with the provided files. I did the following to get the app up and running locally:

- Ran `jss setup` to establish the values in `scjssconfig.json`. (it seems like you have already done this)
- Ran `jss deploy config` to deploy the `/sitecore/config/my-first-jss-app.config` file to the Sitecore instance. (it seems like you have already done this, otherwise you'd likely be seeing a different error)
- Ran `jss deploy package --includeContent` to generate the app manifest (with route data) and deploy it to Sitecore.

> Note: the `jss` commands assume you have the JSS CLI installed globally. If not, prefix the commands with either `npm run` or `yarn`, depending on which package manager you use. e.g. `npm run jss deploy package --includeContent`.

The app was created in Sitecore successfully and I was able to browse to the home route in integrated mode without error.

Can you confirm that your import ran without error? You should see something like this in Sitecore under `/sitecore/content`:

[image: 1]
`

Comment: H Adam
Quite strange I have followed the exact same steps but when previewing the home node I am getting the below error.
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxa16.local\dist\my-first-jss-app\server.bundle.js:1:56408 at at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.d__7`1.MoveNext()

Comment: Can you try browsing to the Layout Service URL for the Home item? `http://my-first-jss-app.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=YOUR_API_KEY` where YOUR_API_KEY is a valid SSC api key. Instructions for setting up a key if you don't already have one: https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/sitecore-config?id=step-2-api-key (note: substitute `jssadvancedappreactweb` with your host name). Once you're able to browse to the Layout Service URL, please paste the output here.

Comment: Hi Adam
I have mailed you all the details from my mail Id : jagatheeshmenon@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Adam,
The issue is with SXA which was installed with the instance and it looks like jss doesn't support SXA. Do we have any work around :)

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue with SXA, Is there any inputs to resolve this issue?